# webpack with Angular2 typescript

Tags: webpack, angular, ts-loader

I'm trying to setup webpack with Angular2 (using TypeScript). It should be a breeze according to [video tutorial on Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j9w5hFit5rM). The guy is using [this Github repo](https://github.com/pkozlowski-opensource/ng2-webpack-play) as an example. So I cloned that github repo to start with and basically did everything that the guy did in the video tutorial.

But when I load my page then all it says is "Loading...". It never really loads the angular component. There are also no errors in the console. Acording to the  "Network" tab in Chrome it seems to be loading my `bundle.js` file fine.

Bundling with `webpack` also gives no errors at all.

I have no clue why this isn't working for me. This is what I have:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
  <my-app>Loading...</my-app>

  <script src="bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Typescript files are exactly like they are on angular.io
app.component.ts

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: '<h1>My First Angular 2 App</h1>'
})
export class AppComponent { }
```

boot.ts

```
import {bootstrap}    from 'angular2/platform/browser'
import {AppComponent} from './app.component'
bootstrap(AppComponent);
```

And my webpack config file:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: {
      app: "./src/boot",

      // load addintional libs (disabled for now)
      vendors: [
        //__dirname + "/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"
      ]
  },
  output: {
    path: __dirname, 
    filename: "./dist/bundle.js"
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.ts']
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.ts/, loaders: ['ts-loader'], exclude: /node_modules/
    }]
  }
};
```

Everything else, like the `tsconfig.js` comes directly from the github repo.

Anyone any idea why my component isn't loading?

---

## Update

Sort of managed to get it to work. The problem was that I defined `entry` as an object. But it works when I assign it as a string:

```
...
entry: './src/boot',
...
```

Now when I load my `index.html` my component loads fine. But when I trigger the build with webpack I do still get **a lot** of errors in console.

```
...
ERROR in C:\xampp\htdocs\repo\node_modules\angular2\bundles\typings\es6-shim\es6-shim.d.ts
(283,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'MAX_SAFE_INTEGER'.

ERROR in C:\xampp\htdocs\repo\node_modules\angular2\bundles\typings\es6-shim\es6-shim.d.ts
(290,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'MIN_SAFE_INTEGER'.

ERROR in C:\xampp\htdocs\repo\node_modules\angular2\bundles\typings\es6-shim\es6-shim.d.ts
(346,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'flags'.

ERROR in C:\xampp\htdocs\repo\node_modules\angular2\bundles\typings\es6-shim\es6-shim.d.ts
(498,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'prototype'.

ERROR in C:\xampp\htdocs\repo\node_modules\angular2\bundles\typings\es6-shim\es6-shim.d.ts
(561,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'size'.

ERROR in C:\xampp\htdocs\repo\node_modules\angular2\bundles\typings\es6-shim\es6-shim.d.ts
(570,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'prototype'.

ERROR in C:\xampp\htdocs\repo\node_modules\angular2\bundles\typings\es6-shim\es6-shim.d.ts
(581,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'size'.

ERROR in C:\xampp\htdocs\repo\node_modules\angular2\bundles\typings\es6-shim\es6-shim.d.ts
(590,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'prototype'.

ERROR in C:\xampp\htdocs\repo\node_modules\angular2\bundles\typings\es6-shim\es6-shim.d.ts
(605,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'prototype'.

ERROR in C:\xampp\htdocs\repo\node_modules\angular2\bundles\typings\es6-shim\es6-shim.d.ts
(619,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'prototype'.
...
```

Comment: You're missing the [`angular2-polyfills.js`](https://github.com/pkozlowski-opensource/ng2-webpack-play/blob/master/index.html#L12) file.

Comment: @EricMartinez Doesn't seem to make any difference. Keep having the same issue.

Comment: Uhmmm... hard to say. The only weird thing I see is that your output points to `dist/bundle.js` and in your html you're using `src="bundle.js"`. Can you make a repo?

Comment: @EricMartinez I've managed to get it working. Only thing I had different was the `entry` part in the webpack config. I defined that as an object instead of a string like in the tutorial. But, eventhough it works, webpack does spit out a ton of errors. I made a repo with what I have right now. Maybe you can still have a look too see if you have an idea on how to fix the errors? https://goo.gl/f5UTPH

Comment: Try this [repo](https://github.com/AntJanus/angular2-ts-starter-kit), it's up-to-date with the latest Angular2 beta and uses webpack.

Answer (score 1):

The duplicate errors are because typings has duplicate definition files in its browser and main dirs. If you look in typings.d.ts you will see both included there. They are included in lines that looks like the following:

```
/// <reference path="../typings/browser.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="../typings/main.d.ts" />
```

If you remove the main.d.ts line from that file and run webpack again, the errors should go away.

I still don't really know what those two are for, but my project runs in a browser so I removed the main.d.ts line. I assume everyone has to remove one, but I could be wrong there. (if anyone wants to pipe in).
-Jeff

Answer (score 0):

According to Angular2 quickstart, you need to include all necessary libraries (https://angular.io/guide/quickstart)

```
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>
```

Comment: With webpack you don't have to include all those libs anymore (except maybe for polyfill). That's the idea behind webpack. It finds all the references for you.